# Supporting types in unified python 2/3 version

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've got some code written with python 2.7.x that I'm trying to make compatible with python 3.x.  I've resolved most of the issues converting the code to work under both versions, but wanted advice dealing with int/long types.

Much of the work to unify int and long types occurred in much earlier (2.4.x) releases and the distinction was completely removed in V3 ( The '1L' format is no longer valid).  At the same time the types module was modified to remove references to types already built-in and the redundant 'long' built-in type was removed.

So under V2.x I still need to support code like:

```
if type(var) == int or type(var) == long :
     do_stuff
```

or

```
if type(var) == int :
     do_int_stuff
elif type(var) == long :
     do_long_stuff
```

But with V3 there is no built-in class for long, and no need to do_long_stuff that's different from normal do_int_stuff.  The built-in class type variable 'long' is no longer defined, so this code would fail with a NameError.

One easy solution is to define 'long' as None or some other nonsense type under v3, understanding type(var) != long for any var.  The long built-in class type defined under v2.x would remain the same.

```
if sys.version_info.major == 3 :
     long = None
```

Is None the best value to use?  In my case setting 'long = int' isn't what I want to use.

Comment: I don't think this contributes to your problem, but consider using `isinstance(x,y)` instead of `type(x) == y`

Comment: When would you need to do `long`-specific stuff instead of regular `int` stuff? The only place `long` behaves differently is when using `repr(1L)` vs. `repr(1)`, the `L` is appended. That's easily remedied by using `str()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply, this makes things much cleaner.

The long-specific stuff is primarily dealing with 2.7 idiosyncrasies, like the cleaning up the trailing L in 2.7 output or recasting long results as int.  99% of the cases are like the first where your suggestions work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should never use `type(obj) == type_obj`; use the [`isinstance()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance), always. Rarely do you need to ignore subclasses, and if you do need to ignore subclasses you can use `type(obj) is type_obj` instead.

`isinstance()` can take a *tuple* of types:

```
isinstance(obj, (int, long))
```

which then allows you to use a variable:

```
try:
    integer_types = (int, long)
except NameError:
    integer_types = int

if isinstance(obj, integer_types):
```

Note that I swapped out the `integer_types` definition based on a `NameError` here, not on a version test. Now your code is compatible with both Python 2 and 3, as well as with any other hypothetical Python build where there is no `long` type.

Comment: This is absolutely correct -- My only concern is that OP seems to be treating `int` and `long` _differently_ in the original code (which is likely another real problem needing to be fixed in the original code)...

Comment: And, for some real fun, you could add in that you can do `isinstance` checks using ABCs!  e.g. `isinstance(obj, numbers.Integral)`

Comment: @mgilson: exactly, addressed that in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, if I'm going to do type checking in python, I prefer to check against an abstract base class where possible.  In this case, there exists [`numbers.Integral`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral) which might work nicely...

```
>>> import numbers
>>> isinstance(1, numbers.Integral)
True
>>> isinstance(1L, numbers.Integral)
True
>>> isinstance(1., numbers.Integral)
False
```

This should work on both python2.x and python3.x.

---

Of course, this answer (and all the others proposed so far) assume that you actually want to do the same thing if the number is an `int` *or* a `long`.
Any code which wants to do something different depending on whether it has an `int` or `long` seems scary and it is hopeless to try to port that directly to python3.x as `long` simply does not exist making that codepath is effectively dead.

Comment: I like your use of numbers, that avoids the need to define unnecessary variables.  As I explained in a previous comment the use of 'special code' for longs is primarily to address 2.7 idiosyncrasies.   These are handled for us in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I like Martijn's answer, but would wrap it like

```
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    is_int  = lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, long))
    is_long = lambda x: isinstance(x, long)
else:
    # Python 3.x
    is_int  = lambda x: isinstance(x, int)
    is_long = lambda x: False
```

which you can use like

```
if is_int(var):
    do_something(var)
```

or

```
if is_long(var):
    do_long_stuff(var)
elif is_int(var):
    do_int_stuff(var)
```